# Yet again an FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF partition issue

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

***Update June 10th Partition seams to be back, almost, please check update 4 at the bottom***

This is happening on a Macbook Pro June 2012 version.
Disk is a 1T SSD and it was up to date with Mojave till about 1 week ago when i started to face this issue. Quick background on the issue : I have tried to make a doualboot with Windows 10.
Issue was that, i realised while installing, i only had a Win 7 key, so I aborted out of the install (with the power button :/ ) Starting from there I was always forced to boot with option key and choose the Mac partition.
After some time even that was failing. In the first couple of tries to solve this (recovery mode disk util) i have tried deleting the win/dualboot partion.

Yesterday i have tried following some threads from here to re set the type (i do not remember what was the actual type before)

```
    Last login: Tue Jun  4 20:41:03 on console
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user name] [-u
            user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid] file ...
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo diskUtil list

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS disk0s2                 464.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        34.6 GB    disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               951.0 GB   disk1s2
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1857421824      2  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
  1857831464    95693671         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk1
Unmount of all volumes on disk1 was successful
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk1
Password:
/dev/disk1s2 removed
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk1
Unmount of all volumes on disk1 was successful
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo gpt add -b 409640 -i 3 -s 1857421824 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1
Password:
/dev/disk1s3 added
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk1
Unmount of all volumes on disk1 was successful
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo gpt remove -i " /dev/disk1
> 
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk1
/dev/disk1s3 removed
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk1
Unmount of all volumes on disk1 was successful
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 1857421824 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1
/dev/disk1s2 added
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1857421824      2  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1857831464    95693671         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$
```

After all this (this is actual export of the terminal) I have again removed the partition and added it back as core storage
`sudo gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 1857421824 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1`.

But still noting.
Actually now when typing this and looking at other threads I am assuming I have skipped a last step that is verify and maybe repair the volume ?
I mean only thing i was doing to "check" if my changes worked was to see in disk util if the partition shows up (which it doesnt)

Also last bit of info, this terminal is of an Mountain Lion install (I replaecd the drive with an old and did an internet recovery) the SSD is hooked up on USB.

### Question/Goal

Is to be able to boot from the partition or at least to be able to access it for data recovery/backup

## Update

I have also tried

```
sudo gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 1857421824 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1
```

Still no luck :(
Is there a way to somehow check the actual type the partition was initially ? The disk was in since at El Capitain, maybe it never got converted to APFS ? I really do not remember....

## UPDATE 2

I have updated my new disk to mojave. Here is the result of the diskutil list now, any ideas ?

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         499.9 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS500                18.4 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 23.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                506.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         951.0 GB   disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
```

## Update 3

So I have played arround a bit more and dumped the content of the first 3 sectors so that shows it is supposed to be a APFS partition and the size is also correct (dump cut of after the first 5 lines)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk2   count=3 skip=409640 | hexdump -Cv
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
1536 bytes transferred in 0.000415 secs (3702558 bytes/sec)
00000000  5d d7 76 29 e6 ed 08 36  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |].v)...6........|
00000010  52 ae 0f 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |R...............|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  40 c0 d6 0d 00 00 00 00  |NXSB....@.......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  94 44 01 4e ef c7 4e a6  |.........D.N..N.|
```

So dunno what to do... verify definitely gives error on the volume (disk seams ok) :

```
diskutil verifyDisk disk2
Started partition map verification on disk2
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Checking the partition map size
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition's size
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content
Checking all HFS data partition loader spaces
Checking booter partitions
Checking Core Storage Physical Volume partitions
The partition map appears to be OK
Finished partition map verification on disk2
MacBook-Pro-de-hnam:~ hnam$ diskutil verifyVolume disk2s2
Started file system verification on disk2s2
Verifying storage system
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x /dev/disk2s2
Checking the container superblock
Checking the EFI jumpstart record
Checking the space manager
error: (oid 0x6d3a) cib: invalid o_cksum (0x7168ff8d27a319ca)
error: failed to read spaceman cib 0x6d3a
Space manager is invalid
The volume /dev/disk2s2 could not be verified completely
Storage system check exit code is 0
Finished file system verification on disk2s2
```

Also there is clearly a free space of about 50 GB at 1857831464    95693671
That is the old windows partition that i have deleted, is that posing an issue ? I tired to do a hexdump at 1857831464 it came up empty

## Update 4

Today something strange happened.
I have ran iBoySoft freeware for a scan only, thinking I was ready to pay for the recovery if it looks doable.
And i saw most of my data with the folder structure intact and all.
At this moment i decided to put my disk back into the laptop from the USB enclosure.
Now the error was not paying attention in between iBoysoft and moving the disk but once all was done I saw my SSD in the finder !!! Dunno did iBoysoft correct something or was the USB enclosure possing a problem...

**I still can not boot from it (holding option while booting only shows MACOS500) any idea on that ?**

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         499.9 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         951.0 GB   disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +951.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Mac OS                  332.9 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.5 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                522.5 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.9 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS500                22.3 GB    disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 23.8 MB    disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                506.8 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk3s4
```

Any idea how to make it bootable again ?

Comment: You have the right idea, but you should have used `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`. Mountain Lion will not be able to recognize the volumes on this drive even after entering `gpt add -b 409640 -i 3 -s 1857421824 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1`.

Comment: Thanks David, so once i change the type what should i do ? Reboot in internet recovery mode ? and verify / repair there ?

Comment: You can not verify or repair from Mountain Lion. You will have to restart and hold down the option key to see if the USB drive is recognized. If successful, you should be able to boot from the USB drive.

Comment: Sorry, the command should have been: `gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 1857421824 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1`

Comment: Yep i also made the same mistake the first time (-i 3) no issues I spoted that. Ok will try this later in the evening when i get home. Thanks ! I'll keep you posted

Comment: This has great detail. Mind editing in a question at the end. What do you want to do? What is the end result you seek?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, nope it did not work, I did not get any option to boot. This disk was in since at least EL Capitan, is it possible it never got converted to APFS ?

Comment: Hi, I added some new info, mostly updated to Mojave to see things better does this give some more ideas ?